# Azure App Services: assembly specified in application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup.deps.json) not found

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-appservice

I have a .net core 2.1 application that is hosted on Microsoft Azure App Service.

It worked for a couple of years and hasn't been updated in the last year.

But it stop with error in stdout:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup', version: '2.2.0'
    path: 'lib/netcoreapp2.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup.dll'
```

Also it still works well in IIS in a virtual machine.

Comment: Other app continue work well with net core 2.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got the similar issue yesterday.
After digging up into this and hadn't found solution, I've created support ticket to Microsoft.

They provided the following recommendations:

> 1. Publish with:
>
> ```
> <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>False</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
> ```
>
> 2. Upgrade to .NET Core 2.2

These steps helped me and application returned back to online.

Looks like they stopped support of .NET Core 2.1 version on their Azure App Services. Check this link for detalis:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-august-21-2021/

PS: As far as I can tell, .NET Core 2.2 might be gone soon too. So I'm focusing to move my application to .NET Core 3.1 shortly.

Comment: Hi! I am in .NET Core 3.1 and still experiencing this. Any updates? Thanks.

Comment: @onihime Hi, what's an issue do you get in logs?